# Eisenstein series for non congruence subgoups

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, eisenstein-series

What is the present status of the Eisenstein series for noncongruence subgroups?
I am aware of work of A. Scholl and  Rohrlich work on the subject. 
Is there any specific examples that has been computed after Scholl's initial paper?